# HTML ignores link directive, and makes no request

Tags: html, css

I am making a login screen, and trying to attach css to my file, but the CSS is not being loaded, as in no request is made, no errors are thrown, the `link` tag is ignored

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- This doesn't work -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" src="/static/css/skeleton.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" src="/static/css/normalize.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" src="/static/css/main.css"/>

        <script src="/static/js/login.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <form>
            <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="Email">
            <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password">
            <button type="button" onclick="loginClick()">Login</button>
        </form>
        <p id="errorMessage"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

***I am running a web server that handles redirection by itself***, but here is my hierarchy

[image: hierarchy]

Comment: check the Network tab in developer tools

Comment: @Yousaf as I said, no request to get the CSS is made, only `login.js` and `favicon.ico` are being requested

Comment: Could you provide us with a screenshot of your directory hierarchy?

Comment: @NicoShultz added, but i am running a web server, so it is probably irrelevant

Comment: Oh, you are using `src=` instead of `href=`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do here is replace

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" src="/static/css/skeleton.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" src="/static/css/normalize.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" src="/static/css/main.css"/>
```

With this code :

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/skeleton.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/normalize.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/main.css"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

The link tag uses `href` instead of `src`, all you need is to substitute the attribute name.

**Before:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" src="/static/css/skeleton.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" src="/static/css/normalize.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" src="/static/css/main.css"/>
```

**After:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/skeleton.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/normalize.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/main.css"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use `src` for including files to your HTML in header. you need to replace all the `src` with `href`. Also consider following standards and adding the type `type="text/css"`

in the end you should have this;

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/skeleton.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/normalize.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/main.css"/>
```